# replace characters in a input text using lists

Tags: python

I wanna use lists;
by that I mean a = b in a list

```
let = {
"a", "b" (meaning a is b)
}
```

then how can I use this list to replace all characters in a input string

```
string = "stringa"

characters = [
    "a", "b",
]
dic =  {} 
for l1 in zip(characters):
    dic[l1]
    
result = ""
for letter in string:
    result = result + dic[letter]
print(result)

input('Press Any Key To Exit')
```

I tried this but it didnt work any help is appeciarated

Comment: what error does it show you?   in the 'dic[l1]' line, I think you should assign a value to it '(dic[l1] = something')

Comment: dic[l1]
    ~~~^^^^
KeyError: ('a',) i get this error

Comment: can you try to assign a value there as I showed in the previous comment, and write here if it solves the problem?

Comment: also, I am not sure why you need to zip characters?

Comment: zip with only 1 list?

Comment: zip() has no purpose in your code. Just use `for ... in characters`

Comment: still same issue, even if it did work I dont wanna use dic cuz it makes it messier this was a some sample I found on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the `zip(characters)` line.

you need more than one list inorder to zip.
When you do zip to just one list, the output is as seen here:

```
c = ['a','b']
for i in zip(c):
  print(i)

# ('a',)
# ('b',)
```

and this also is what your error shows you `KeyError: ('a',)`

---

EDIT:

if you want to have "stringa" converted to "stringb" you have another issue.
What you need to do is:

```
string = "stringa"
dic = {'a':'b', 'b':'a'}
result = ""
for letter in string:
    if letter in dic.keys():
       letter = dic[letter]
    result+=letter
print(result)

# stringb
```

Comment: i tried removing the zip
and I think you got the lists wrong, its not multiple values I want one to be equal to the other think it like a = b or vice versa

Comment: try dic = {'a':'b', 'b':'a'}   without characters and without l1. does it solve your problem?

Comment: and I still dont understand what you are trying to do with 'result'

Comment: what do you mean by that, im kind of trying to make a cipher

Comment: plz look at my edit to this answer

Comment: yes I exactly need that. But how come i can make a singular list that will for example assign a to b and b to a how would I do that, cuz im getting error with current code

Comment: and no i tried doing dic = {'a':'b', 'b':'a'} and it doesnt seem like it worked, I dontn wanna use dic at all I wanna use a list

Comment: look at latest edit, i checked, the code works!

Comment: cant ı use a list?

Comment: I think you'll need two lists, no? otherwise how do you know what maps to what in a list? I would highly recommend to use a dictionary in this case (or I just dont understand your usecase correctly).

Comment: I had somewhat similiar code it was something like this
https://pastebin.com/LFsHJK4K

Comment: this is a very bad way to do it, but basically you have to look at all the even indices in your list and then change them with the next odd index. This is IMO a very bad implementation I would strongly advise against. But maybe you find another better solution using lists as you want. If you are satisfied with the dict implementation feel free to accept the answer &/ upvote . good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When converting a list into a dictionary, you use slices to turn the list into two, for zipping together. `zip` returns a tuple iterator, so you need two `for` loop variables:

```
for l1, l2 in zip(characters[::2], characters[1::2]):
    dic[l1] = l2
    dic[l2] = l1
```

The `[::2]` gets every other character starting with the first one. The `[1::2]` gets every other character starting with the second one.

If you want to avoid a dictionary, and do a two-way replacement, then one way to do it is to do the replacements in the `zip` loop:

```
result = string
for l1, l2 in zip(characters[::2], characters[1::2]):
  result = result.replace(l1, '#')
  result = result.replace(l2, l1)
  result = result.replace('#', l2)
```

The `#` is a temporary placeholder to avoid undoing the replacement we just did. You can set that to be any character that won't show up in the strings.

Comment: i tried this but im not getting any output

Comment: @lunar The code samples are meant to replace the loops you already have. You need to add the `print(result)` statement. If you want to test it and get output, you can run a full example [here](https://replit.com/@zacharyjohnson2/StackOverflow#main.py).

Comment: I have a similiar code to this https://pastebin.com/raw/jgEm4mrV im getting:     for l1, l2 in zip(characters[::2], characters[1::2]):
                      ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @lunar You have the characters in curly braces `{` `}` which creates a set, not a list. You need the square braces `[` `]`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mehme\OneDrive\Masaüstü\text encoder\encode.py", line 13, in <module>
    result = result + dic[letter]
KeyError: 's'
what is this error suppose to mean

Comment: @lunar If you want to iterate over the string instead of using `replace`, you have to account for the dictionary not having every letter. Use `result = result + dic.get(letter, letter)` to use the letter in the string if a replacement isn't found.